# Cluster deployment with gitlab ci shell runner

Tags: continuous-integration, continuous-deployment, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner

I've trying to migrate our CI and CD processes from Jenkins to Gitlab CI. How should I setup gitlab to build our application in cluster?

In general, I expect gitlab clone repository to all nodes in cluster, execute my Bash deployment script and run some tests if needed. From my point of view, I think I should start runners in all cluster nodes and start build with all neccessary tasks. Is it possible in Gitlab? I can start only one runner for one build. May be there are some different approaches for this task? 
For example, I have cluster with 2 nodes, A and B. I need clone repository to both nodes and start build script on each of them. I have register one gitlab-ci-multi-runner on each node, but build executed only on one of this node.

Answer (score 0):

What you are describing can be achieved by setting up each executor with a different tag and setting multiple build tasks in gitlab (yaml anchors help with it) but it's not the desired way. The desired way would be to use gitlab runner to run tests and then another build to run Ansible/Chef/Salt/Puppet or your other desired deployment tool.